# 1.8kVdc to 700Vdc voltage dropper

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, linear-regulator

I'm trying to get some ideas for dropping 1.8kVdc to 700Vdc using simple voltage dropping techniques/topologies. I am using a SMPS (Switched Mode Power Supply) to regulate the low voltage outputs from there. The load power is roughly 20W. Could someone suggest me a way forward?

**Edit1:** Adding more details-20W is the maximum load power, load power is variable. I have achieved efficiency of 87% with the second stage(i.e.700Vdc to low voltages SMPS). This smps would be delivering power to control electronics. Product is industrial requirement, PD2 rated, has to operate with internal ambient up to 85degC.

Need to select topology for the first stage considering simple & cost effective design because the second stage is well regulated. I don't have a figure on the new efficiency requirement; need to get the best efficiency possible.

**Edit2:** Second stage is not removable due to multiple use of this SMPS in various products. But this is editable, For eg: transformer, mosfet etc., could be re-designed. It is preferable to opt for dropping 1.8kV to 700V though. 700Vdc needn't be strictly regulated.

Comment: 1st : you can convert it to AC and then use a transformer, then convert the AC signal to DC in the output of transformer.  2nd you can use DC to DC converters.

Comment: You could do a simple buck converter at a fixed duty cycle, since you don't need the output to be regulated, but that wouldn't be the most efficient method.

Comment: Please add some details to your question to get better answers: Can you say something about the load?  Is the 20W power constant, or is it variable with a maximum of 20W?  What kind of environment is this going into?  Do you have any requirements for efficiency of the conversion?  (Please add these to the question.)

Comment: @Theodore I've added more details.

Comment: I would eliminate the dual stage and make a coplanar PCB 10 mil track:gap transformer on opposite sides of the board with a 3:1 OD:ID ratio switching regulator inside a shielded enclosure without the thermal effects of ferrite and 50kV/mm insulation of FR4

Comment: @Hearth That is nice approach, but I guess the cost of the design would become large and may not be a effective solution as you said. It would become two stage regulation.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thanks for the nice suggestion. To add, this circuit would be part of bigger board, meaning the board houses lot other circuits.

Comment: That can hardly be something common in the household. I am therefore assuming industrial applications. Can you give more information about where the voltage is coming from and what you want to supply with it?

Comment: @arnisz Yes, this is specific requirement and would be supplied for industries. Input is 1kV L-L 3 phase supply, rectified and makes about 1.4kV and with more margin makes up about 1.8kVdc. I don't have clear idea from this is coming.

Comment: High voltage or high power EMI must be boxed separately like in Pc’s unless you know better

Comment: We build a very reliable flyback at 1200 V in and 24V, 2 A out. You can make a separate secondary winding for feedback and get pretty good regulation, and the secondary circuit can be completely transformer isolated so the high voltage doesn't get into the low voltage if something fails.  We fully encapsulate.